# Selenium, how to Copy a few words that are always different?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to copy automatically a Name out of the webbrowser but the Name changes so I don't know how to copy it.

I've tried to doublecklick it or to "ctrl + c" it but it didn't work.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://realnamecreator.alexjonas.de/?l=de#");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("[+] Filter-Optionen")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("gender")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("gender"))).selectByVisibleText("w");
    driver.findElement(By.id("gender")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();
```

and after this I want to copy the name into my Program. So I would say 
String text = driver...

Comment: can you shear the HTML of the element that holds the name?

Comment: Im not sure but the id ="realname" and its h1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use thread-sleep... use WebDriverWait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("realname")));
```

Then use `getText()`:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("realname")).getText()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

First you need to retrieve the element, then call the `getText` method documented [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("realname")).getText()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Omg thanks i already tried that but after your comment I had the Idea to let the thread sleep so it can load. My problem was I copied something that was there a few milliseconds after. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MuhammedDemir it is not recommended to use thread sleep... use `WebDriverWait`

Answer (score 0):

The link you have shared has the element with `realname` id before it generates and shows the name.
So waiting for visibility of the element with id `realname` would not give you the expected result.

You have to wait for the invisibility of the image that shows on the page load but doesn't show when the name is shown.

Try this,

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#realname > a")));
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("realname")).getText();
```